How to adjust custom policy template to phone + MFA
I am following this custom policy template example for B2C user deletion. It works fine for email sign up, however, we are using phone signup + SMS MFA. Can this policy be updated to that?
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/delete-my-account
Thanks a lot!

Yes, you can.
You need to change the policy to allow phone sign-in as per here.

Thanks, I will have a go at it.
